# Calculating Cumulative Field Values in ArcMap using a case field in ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I want to calculate cumulative field values using an case field from another column in ArcGIS 10.4.

For example, if I have an "ID" column and "Count" column inside my attribute table, I want to calculate cumulative values for each ID separately.

I have used this:

[Calculating Cumulative Field Values in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116157/calculating-cumulative-field-values-in-arcmap) [image]

I can do that if I select all rows with the same ID and run the field calculator, but that is a lot of manual work, so I want to use "ID" field as case field.

What is the best way to do that?
[Calculating Cumulative Field Values in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116157/calculating-cumulative-field-values-in-arcmap/116158#116158)

[image]

Comment: This is my attribute table: https://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/ls0pba738cdjbqik8c8k060pru_cumulative.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible using for example dictionaries etc. (for example see: [Numbering of objects based on several fields in ArcGIS with ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359213/numbering-of-objects-based-on-several-fields-in-arcgis-with-arcpy?noredirect=1#comment587750_359213)) I would use pandas (which is included ArcMap >=10.4). When your data is in a pandas dataframe you can do any proccessing you can Think of.

```
import pandas as pd
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\ak_riks.shp"
fields = ['LANSKOD','area'] #field to group by, field with values to cumulative sum
field_to_calculate = 'cumsum'

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields), columns=fields) #Create a pandas dataframe using da.SearchCursor
df2 = df.groupby(fields[0])[fields[1]].cumsum() #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847800/how-can-i-use-cumsum-within-a-group-in-pandas
givecumsum = iter(df2.to_list()) #Iterator to return one value at a time
#givecumsum = iter(list(df2)) #If above line does not work

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,field_to_calculate) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = next(givecumsum)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Screenshot from Pro but the code for ArcMap is the same:
[image]

Comment: I have a .dbf table, not a shapefile, is there a difference in code? Also, is there a way to do that from the field calculator?

Comment: Try it and see if it works

Comment: When I run the Python window and set my path and column names it doesn`t work.

Comment: What could be a problem there?

Comment: "Doesnt work" give no useful info so impossible to say.

Comment: Nothing happend when I paste the code and set my path and column names in Python window from ArcMap 10.4.

Comment: How can you tell? Have you updated cache in ArcMap attribute table?

Comment: How to do that?  How to update cache?

Comment: I meant to say reload cache: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/refreshing-a-table.htm

Comment: This is the message now: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2083, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_list'

Comment: That is helpful. I dont know why it does not work, but try: `givecumsum = iter(list(df2))` instead of `givecumsum = iter(df2.to_list())`

Answer (score 1):

I save my field calculator expressions in the same folder.
They are easily located by name and this is why I often prefer them over scripts, especially when execution time is not an issue.

So with slight modification of [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154), accumulation by group can be achieved by using:

```
d={}
def GroupOrder(groupID,toSum):
  N=d.get(groupID,0);N+=toSum
  d[groupID]=N
  return N
#--------------
GroupOrder(!to_node!, !Shape_Length!)
```